# Refactor letter wildcard statement

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

How can I refactor this to work with each letter (a to z) I don't want to have to re-write the query for every letter.

**Display HTML:**

```
<div class="questionWrapper">
  <div class="question">
    <h3>A</h3>
    <?php foreach ($categoryA as $category) : ?>
       <p class="view"><?= $category['category']; ?></p>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
  </div>
</div>
```

**Query example:**

```
$categoryA = query('SELECT * FROM category WHERE category LIKE "A%"',
  array('category' => ['category']),
  $conn);

$categoryB = query('SELECT * FROM category WHERE category LIKE "B%"',
  array('category' => ['category']),
  $conn);
```

**Function:**

```
function query($query, $bindings, $conn)
{
    $stmt = $conn->prepare($query);
    $stmt->execute($bindings);
    return $stmt;
}
```

Comment: Use a for loop as you are doing.  You're on the right track, just for loop the alphabet if you're using a-z (definitelY).  `foreach(range('a','z') as $i) {
  if($string == $i) {
    echo $i;
  }
}
`  Then, for your query: ... "WHERE category LIKE '".$i."%'"; in your for loop.

Comment: If you're doing this frequently, you might want to add a `category_first_letter` column or something of the sort that can be indexed properly. Also, why aren't you using a placeholder in your query when you're clearly trying to? `category LIKE :category`.

Comment: Do you mean all the category results in one query?  Also not sure what $bindings is doing there, as your passing string literals in the query, id also change around your input order for the function query($conn, $query, $bindings = array())

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it for you to be using the placeholder:

```
$category = query('SELECT * FROM category WHERE category LIKE :category',
  array(':category' => '%'.$letter.'%'),
  $conn);
```

Comment: Whats this?  Can you explain it please, I don't know what your doing here.

Comment: Your answer is showing up in the Low Quality Posts review queue.  Please consider expanding it to add an explanation of what your code is doing and why.